# iOS build fails due to RNFirebase's collision with use_frameworks! in Podfile

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to implement a third party Native SDK into my iOS app but it fails on RNFirebase(v5) if I enable `use_frameworks!` to dynamically load it as a framework.

I get such errors: `React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found`

Couldn't upload screenshot here due to stackoverflow's `reputation points` but see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxIt7.png) on imgur.

I know that there is another version(v6) of RNFirebase library and has breaking changes to mitigate but I'm not sure if it'll have similar problem.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What react native version are you using?
RN firebase v6 solves this issue btw [changelog](https://rnfirebase.io/releases/v6.0.0#general-library-changes)

Comment: @LonelyCpp I'm using RN 61.5
Regarding the RN firebase v6 fix, they're very ambiguou in their explaniation.
Underneath the fix for `use_frameworks`, they said the following:
`Note: Currently this has been disabled as use_frameworks! support in React Native was broken again in RN60. We'll re-enable in a future release for RN61.`, so not sure if it's fixed?

Comment: RN 61 [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0610) says they have fixed `use_frameworks`.